# Set Session Variable in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can i set session variable in DRF view(APIView) and get it in other views of my API.
when I set session in any views like

```
request.session['name'] = 'SRJ'
```

I can access this in same view but I cant get it in other views files of API.
i know request of django and DRF are different but is there a way to do it ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The request object is shared throughout the session. Setting `request.session['name'] = 'SRJ'` should allow you to grab the name in another view that has the request object as parameter, for example after setting `name` you can check it in another view with:

```
if request.session['name'] == 'SRJ':
    pass
```

You can also delete the session variable like this: `del request.session['name']`

Django and DRF do not make a difference, they both use the same django request object. This is all I can give you from the question, let me know if this is not your problem.

Comment: I dont know what are your trying to say. i didn't get anything. that what you are saying is working on django views but not in drf views

Comment: it should work for any views! The same `request` object should get passed to any view. Did you try setting the session variable in one view and check it in another and that did not work?

Comment: yeah i did the same that you are saying but there is not any session variable. but I think now i get it why is this happening. actually i am sending token of user in every request to authenticate user in API, could this be a problem what do you think.

Comment: I assume you are using `TokenAuthentication`. If so then the best option would be to probably save the "session" data in a table and get it from there. `request.session` does not work if you are not using the django `SessionAuthentication`